# How to work with custom SGBD types with jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I'm wondering how to leverage the [new range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html) you can find in the latests versions of PostgresSQL.

I can find the [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) documentation on how to manage normal column with custom Java types, however I cannot find how to use custom-type column into custom Java Types. Is there a documentation, or a piece of existing code in jOOQ I can look into and try to contribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### jOOQ 3.17 range type support

Range type support has been added to jOOQ 3.17.0, see [#2968](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2968). For this, the `jooq-postgres-extensions` module needs to be present on the classpath of the code generator and the runtime, to offer the appropriate bindings and array bindings.

Historic answer for older jOOQ versions:

#### Custom Converter:

However, you can implement support yourself using [jOOQ 3.5 custom data type `Binding`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/). What you essentially need is a `Converter` like this:

```
public class Int4RangeConverter implements Converter<Object, Range<Integer>> {
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?),(.*?)\\)");

    @Override
    public Range<Integer> from(Object t) {
        if (t == null)
            return null;

        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher("" + t);
        if (m.find())
            return Tuple.range(
                Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)), 
                Integer.valueOf(m.group(2)));

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported range : " + t);
    }

    @Override
    public Object to(Range<Integer> u) {
        return u == null ? null : "[" + u.v1 + "," + u.v2 + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Object> fromType() {
        return Object.class;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public Class<Range<Integer>> toType() {
        return (Class) Range.class;
    }
}
```

The above converter uses [jOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL)'s [`org.jooq.lambda.tuple.Range`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jooq/lambda/tuple/Range.java) type, but you can implement your own, or just use `int[]` if you prefer that.

#### Custom Binding

The `Converter` can now be used in a `Binding` like this:

```
public class PostgresInt4RangeBinding implements Binding<Object, Range<Integer>> {

    @Override
    public Converter<Object, Range<Integer>> converter() {
        return new Int4RangeConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void sql(BindingSQLContext<Range<Integer>> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.render()
           .visit(DSL.val(ctx.convert(converter()).value()))
           .sql("::int4range");
    }

    // ...
}
```

[More information about how to use custom data type bindings can be found in the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/). Ideally, you will apply this binding to generated code.

#### Using the `Range` type in SQL:

Using it is simple. Insertion:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .insertInto(T_EXOTIC_TYPES)
   .columns(T_EXOTIC_TYPES.ID, T_EXOTIC_TYPES.RANGE_INT4)
   .values(1, range(1, 5))
   .execute();
```

Selection:

```
assertEquals(range(1, 5), DSL.using(configuration).fetchValue(
    select(T_EXOTIC_TYPES.RANGE_INT4)
    .from(T_EXOTIC_TYPES)
    .where(rangeOverlaps(T_EXOTIC_TYPES.RANGE_INT4, range(0, 2))))
);
```

With the following definition of `rangeOverlaps()`:

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> Condition rangeOverlaps(
    Field<Range<T>> f1, Range<T> f2) {
    return DSL.condition("range_overlaps({0}, {1})", f1, val(f2, f1.getDataType()));
}
```

Comment: How would I go about registering the Binding (in this case Int4RangeConverter) in Java? The manual only shows how to do using xml.

Comment: @singularity: There's a section explaining programmatic configuration http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic. [See also this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39777764/521799)