# Jooq custom binding registration in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, jsonb

I have a custom binding written to convert from custom type to Postgres json type. 
This [part of the documentation](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/) mentions how to register using xml but I'm using Java. I have tried to search to find how to do that but in vain.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If by "I'm using Java", you mean using programmatic code generator configuration using Java:

There's a manual section about programmatic code generator configuration here:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic

Essentially, all XML elements also exist as Java types, which are generated with XJC from the [code generation configuration XSD](http://www.jooq.org/xsd), so all XML configuration maps 1:1 to Java configuration, including that for data type bindings (via `ForcedType` objects).

#### If by "I'm using Java", you mean you don't use the code generator and want to create a binding:

The code generator doesn't do anything magic. Everything it does, you can do manually as well. You can easily call:

```
DataType<MyJsonType> jsonType = 
    SQLDataType.VARCHAR.asConvertedDataType(new MyJsonBinding());
Field<MyJsonType> jsonField = field(name("my_table", "my_column"), jsonType);
```

Of course, using the code generator instead will greatly help...

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I'm not using code generator but only using jooq to create sql and using those sqls executed outside of the system. Here I want to configure some custom binding so that it can generate sqls when I set the custom type values. How do I set custom binding in DSL instance?

Comment: @singularity: I see, I'm sorry I've misunderstood your question. I'll update accordingly

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Appreciate your time and help.